# asyncio sharing variables in queue

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am studying Asyncio and so far I managed to prepare the structure for what I need.

```
import asyncio
import random

async def speed_forever():
    while True:
        speed = random.randint(1,100)
        print("Speed mesuring ......", speed)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def rain_forever():
    while True:
        rain = random.random()
        print("Rain mesuring .......", rain)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def main():
    asyncio.ensure_future(speed_forever())  # fire and forget
    asyncio.ensure_future(rain_forever())  # fire and forget

    while True:
        print("*" * 40)
        print("Sending Data.....")    #Here I'd like to get access to rain and speed variable by using a queue
        print("*" * 40)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Now, I'd like to get access to rain and speed from main() so can do something with those variables (eg sending over the air).

1. How should I implement a queue because I am failing at it?
2. Is the code structure good enough to start implementing the function with the real code?

Comment: `speed_forever` and `rain_forever` should be methods of a class. `speed` and `rain` should be attributes of the same class.

Comment: Would you like to get all the measurements in main (e.g., from the last 5 seconds) or just the very last one?

Comment: The very last available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a skeleton for passing data from the `*_forever` functions back to `main` over a couple of queues. I've marked the new code with '***'

```
import asyncio
import random

rain_q = asyncio.Queue()      # ***
speed_q = asyncio.Queue()     # ***

async def speed_forever():
    while True:
        speed = random.randint(1,100)
        print("Speed mesuring ......", speed)
        await speed_q.put(speed)                 # ***
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def rain_forever():
    while True:
        rain = random.random()
        print("Rain mesuring .......", rain)
        await rain_q.put(rain)                   # ***
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def main():
    asyncio.ensure_future(speed_forever())  # fire and forget
    asyncio.ensure_future(rain_forever())  # fire and forget

    rain = None       # *** 
    speed = None      # ***
    while True:
        print("*" * 40)

        # *** Read stuff from the queues. Here, I'm just using the latest
        # item in the queue - but one can do other things as well. 
        while not rain_q.empty(): 
            rain = await rain_q.get()
        
        while not speed_q.empty(): 
            speed = await speed_q.get()

        print(f"*** Last rain was {rain}")            
        print(f"*** Last speed was {speed}")
        print("Sending Data.....")    #Here I'd like to get access to rain and speed variable by using a queue
        print("*" * 40)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Note that if all you're interested in is the last item in the queue, there are other ways to achieve this. One, for example, would be a global variable of type float with the latest number. I don't think that's the right way to do it in this case.

Comment: I see now speed has got all the values set in the queue. 

Speed was 88
Speed was 44
Speed was 89
Speed was 23
Speed was 82

Is there a way to just fetch most recent speed value from the queue and then clear it?

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you're basically looking for a queue of size 1, which always keeps just the last item?

Comment: yes exactly, I acquire a new value every 3 seconds but probably send out last value (which is averaged) every minute over the air

Comment: If it answers your question, do you mind accepting my answer for future generations?

Comment: The `while` loops in `main()` are not correct. When the queue becomes empty, the inner loop won't be entered, and the outer loop will loop forever. Since the outer loop doesn't `await` anything, no other coroutines will run and get a chance to put something in the queue. The correct (and simpler) approach is to drop the inner loop and simply unconditionally use `rain = await rain_q.get()` in the outer `while True`. If the queue is not empty, that will give the next item. If it's empty, `get()` will pause the current coroutine until an item becomes available - which is exactly what you want.

Comment: I think there also should be a `task_done()` called on `rain_q` and `speed_q` for every `get()` to to indicate that processing of the `get()`ed item is complete so as to not block any future `join()` call.

Comment: @user4815162342 Does the `await asyncio.sleep(5)` at the end of the `while True` loop not work to yield to other coroutines?

Comment: @Dan You're right. The rest of the comment should still apply, though.